# Jquery click trigger on Success or Complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get another function that is on submit button ie. **class="sucessClass"** to be executed on success or complete. Here are my codes :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#send").on("click", function(){

    var name=$("#name").val
    var email=$("#email").val   
    var message=$("#message").val
    var dataString="name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" message;

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "proData.php",
        data: dataStringxx,
        success: function(html){

            |=== sucess function ===|

        }
         else{

        }
}
});


    
    Name :
    Email : 
    Message : 
    Send
```

Comment: $('.successClass').trigger('click');

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: first, use `.val()` not `.val`.  second, put semicolons at the end of those.  and finally - its `success` not `sucess` lol

Comment: Chitowns23 - Thanks - let me try. Deryck - thanks :)

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, so let me know. Maybe add more detail if it doesn't do what you want

Comment: Chitowns24 - thanks - it worked well :) - superb

Comment: I found one issue, it also triggers if data is FALSE. I mean it it fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#send").on("click", function(){

        var name=$("#name").val();
        var email=$("#email").val();   
        var message=$("#message").val();
        var dataString="name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" message;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "proData.php",
            data: dataStringxx,
            success: function(html){
              $('.successClass').trigger('click');   
            }

        });
   });

   $('.successClass').click( function(){
      // write your code here what needs to be done.
   });
```

});

Comment: If this post is the answer to your issue, then you can accept it as answer. It will be useful to the person who will meet the same issue.

Comment: Balaji - it also triggers if data is FALSE. I mean it it fails.